# Sublime text spell checking whilst typing mid-word - How do I prevent this?

Tags: sublime-text-3

As you can see from the image below, I've yet to finish typing the word `string` but Sublime Text 3 *build v3.2.1* shows a spelling error even though the word is not complete or the cursor has left the word boundary.

Is there any way to prevent this?

---

#### Example of typing `string` mid word.

[image]

If you type in any other word processor this behaviour is not there and IMO this can be slightly distracting at times.